# can't exit ubuntu 16.04 trial version

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04

I tried to download Ubuntu 16.04 on my Asus Eee PC Seashell (Windows 7 Starter), trial version loaded no problem, but when trying to install Ubuntu, it gives me error message "no root filesystem defined, please correct from partitions menu." I now try to go back to use Windows, but computer doesn't seem to find it even in secure boot. I tried to press F2 or Esc or Del when booting computer, all it does it gets me to Ubuntu. I think donwloading Ubuntu is too much work with all those partitions, so I just want to go back to using Windows, but can't find the way how.

Answer (score 0):

> "no root filesystem defined, please correct from partitions menu."

During the partition part you MUST mark 1 partition as `/`. That is the root partition where the system is going to be installed.

Comment: I'm not sure that OP is using manual partitioning at all. I've seen and heard of similar error messages during automated partitioning when the installer cannot determine the current partition layout (e. g. because of Windows Dynamic Disks).